# Flutter pigeon inter-referencing @HostApi classes

Tags: flutter, dart, native, flutter-method-channel

Hi there I'm using flutter. However, I have some classes which need to be associated with equivalents on the native side. For this I'm using pigeon. Here is a sample of the pigeon template:

```dart
import 'package:pigeon/pigeon.dart';

@HostApi()
abstract class Aircraft {
  FlightController getFlightController();
  List<Camera> getCameras();
  List<Gimbal> getGimbal();
  Controller getController();
  Radar getRadar();
  List<Lidar> getLidars();
}

@HostApi()
abstract class FlightController {

}

@HostApi()
abstract class Camera {

}

@HostApi()
abstract class Gimbal {

}

@HostApi()
abstract class Controller {

}

@HostApi()
abstract class Radar {

}

@HostApi()
abstract class Lidar {

}
```

When I try creating bindings using flutter pub run pigeon errors are generated on lines 5 to 10 where other HostApi classes are referenced. Why is this the case? When I remove the HostApi annotation and "abstract" it seems to work. But this is not what I need since each of the other classes have native implementations as well.

How should I go about enabling this?